# could someone explain in detail on this ((sum(x[i-n:i+n+1]))..where does i-n:i+n+1 start and end?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

could someone explain in detail on this ((sum(x[i-n:i+n+1]))..where does i-n:i+n+1 start and end??
i just don't want to copy the code`

[The function should create a return a new list r where](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obkcm.png)

```py
def smooth_a(x, n):
    x = [x[0]]*n+x+[x[-1]]*n #creates a copy of x  
    res = [] #empty list     
    for i in range(n, len(x)-n):
        res.append(sum(x[i-n:i+n+1])/(2*n+1)) 
    return res 

x = [1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2] #def of x
print('smooth_a(x, 1): ', smooth_a(x, 1)) #prints new list with n=1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `x = [1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2]` and `n = 1`

Then, if you take `i = 3` for example:

```
sum(x[i-n:i+n+1]) = sum(x[2:5])
                  = sum([6, 4, 5]) <- slices x from 2 to 4, both inclusive
                  = 15
```

For your specific problem, be careful with the lower slice index, if it's negative, the slicing will return an empty list, so I would write it as `sum(x[max(i-n, 0):i+n+1])`.

Comment: so if n=1 and i=0  it will be sum(x[max(-1,0): 0+1+1])????.......or n=1 and i=8????

Comment: In my answer, it would be the first option. The minimum Index for an array slicing on python is 0.